# Nested For Loop Speed up for Performance

Tags: c#, algorithm

*I have a list of list of string in order to group the string with the number of '1' like string = "00000" belongs to the first group and string = "00001" belongs to the second group. ALl String are equal length. Now I compare the first group to the second group and second group to third group and soon...like in the Image. The First element in the first group is compared to all elements of the second group. Until every string are compared. Is There a way to speed up the performance of my program? So I can Achieved 32000 string with 15 Length.*

***Edit***

Sorry for the past post.After reading it i realize I was to dumb asking like that.
The goal of the program was a simplifier. Based on the ***Quine–McCluskey algorithm***

Consider

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

I group them by number of 1

```
000

001
010
100

011
101
110

111
```

Then I compare each string from the group to the next group

```
group 1
000

group 2
001
010
100

group 3
011
101
110

group1 -> group2
------------------
    000 -> 001 = 00-
    000 -> 010 = 0-0
    000 -> 100 = -00
------------------
group2 ->group3
--------------------  
    001 -> 011 = 0-1
    001 -> 101 = -01
    001 -> 110 = no output

    010 -> 011 = 01-
    010 -> 101 = no output
    010 -> 110 = -10

    100 -> 011 = no output
    100 -> 101 = 10-
    100 -> 110 = 1-0

---------------------
etc.
```

then group the output again by number of 1 and compare them again until no strings can be compared.

I need to achieve a 15 variable but it take for ever for the program to finish.Any Idea how to speed it up. I was testing it on threading but just a little improvement.

> Number of Strings: 2048 Length of variable: 11 Time: 10 minutes

***Need to Achieved***

> Number of Strings: 32767 Length of variable: 15 Time: cannot be achieved

```
 List<List<string>> ImplicantsByOneFinal = new List<List<string>>();
 List<List<string>> TermsByOne = new List<List<string>>();
```

is there a way or algorithm to improve this code. it becomes slower on 11 to 15 variables.

```
bool CombineAndGroup(List<List<string>> ImplicantsByOne)
{ 
            TermsByOne = new List<List<string>>();
            int combined = 0; 
            for (int i = 0; i < ImplicantsByOne.Count - 1; i++)
            { 
                List<string> termsGrouped = new List<string>();
                for (int j = 0; j < ImplicantsByOne[i].Count; j++)
                { 
                    int combination = 0;
                    int num1 = Convert.ToInt32((ImplicantsByOne[i][j]).Replace('-','0'), 2); 
                        for (int k = 0; k < ImplicantsByOne[i + 1].Count; k++)
                        { 
                            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32((ImplicantsByOne[i + 1][k]).Replace('-', '0'), 2);
                            int num3 = num2 - num1;
                            double num4 = Math.Log((double)num3, (double)2); 
                            if (((num4 % 1) == 0) && (num3 > 0) && (Esum(ImplicantsByOne[i][j]) == Esum(ImplicantsByOne[i + 1][k])))
                            {  
                                string combinedMinterm = CompareString(ImplicantsByOne[i][j], ImplicantsByOne[i + 1][k]); 
                                if (!termsGrouped.Contains(combinedMinterm))
                                {
                                    termsGrouped.Add(combinedMinterm); 
                                }  

                            }
                        }   
                }
                if (termsGrouped.Count > 0)
                {
                    combined += termsGrouped.Count;
                } 
                TermsByOne.Add(termsGrouped);
            }

            return (combined > 0) ? true : false;
        } 

 private int Esum(String binCode)
        {
            binCode = binCode.Replace('1','0');
            binCode = binCode.Replace('-', '1');
            int esum = Convert.ToInt32(binCode, 2);
            return esum;
        }
//Purpose of CompareString is to compare two string and change the unique char to '-'
//like 000 and 001 = 00-
  private string CompareString(string str1, string str2)
        { 
            if (str1 == str2)
            { 
                CountCompareStringLoops++;
                return str1;
            }
            else 
            { 
                if (str1.Length == 1)
                { 
                    return "-";
                }
                int halflength = str1.Length / 2; 
                return CompareString(str1.Substring(0, halflength), str2.Substring(0, halflength)) + CompareString(str1.Substring(halflength), str2.Substring(halflength)); 
            }
        }
```

***Main Program***

```
 MintermsByOne = Loaded with string 000 001 and so on

CombineAndGroup(MintermsByOne);
 ImplicantsByOneFinal = TermsByOne; 
 while (CombineAndGroup(TermsByOne))
 {
        ImplicantsByOneFinal = TermsByOne; 
 }
```

**Output ImplicantsByOneFinal**

Comment: I smell an XY problem. What is the task you're really trying to achieve?

Comment: Why have you tagged this with c++ and c when it's clearly neither of them? Why have you included c# and c#-4.0 and c#-3.0?

Comment: I like that image, could be my favorite when i want to illustrate that a question is unclear.

Comment: Is the returned value of `CompareString()` useless?

Comment: I have edit my post. Hope I have explained it well

Comment: another Down vote? why?

Comment: It's better to post this question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: i see. thanks i guess i will flag my post.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, to be honest... your description doesn't match your code. (Your code never mentions the character '1', for example. The fact that you never use the result of calling `CompareString` is suspicious too.) LINQ should make implementing your description of "group the string with the number of '1' " easy and efficient:

```
var grouped = strings.GroupBy(x => x.Count(c => c == '1'));
```

That will only count the number of '1' characters in each string once. You never need to compare *any* string with another one.

If this isn't what you're actually trying to do, you need to clarify what your actual aim is.

Comment: @Snippet: Nope, it's still not clear what you mean by "compare the string by group".

Comment: @Snippet: It's still not particularly clear to me, to be honest - but I'd also still recommend using LINQ to express it. It's likely to end up with *much* clearer code.

Comment: thanks @Jon Skeet for the time. I will take your advice and start learning LINQ

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to write C#, but I want to help. So my code is given in Java.
1. I think `==` is an `O(n)` operation, your `CompareString` may be `O(nlgn)` where `n = str1.Length`. Use a simpler and faster `O(n)` way and see if the time decreases:

```
private String CompareString(String str1, String str2) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(i))
            sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
        else
            sb.append('-');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

2. Well, I found out there are a lot of `ToInt32`. Calculate the result of all strings in `ImplicantsByOne` at once and use it later. So does `Esum`.
3. To check if `num3` is a power of two:

```
private boolean isPowerOfTwo(int x) {
    return (x > 0 && (x & (x - 1)) == 0);
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the help.I used that already and i test the possible loop of that from my new one. for a string of length is 8 that loop compares 8 times, in  new one it compares 4 times. I know the my codes worst case scenario is if there are too many different characters but i catch the string that it will only have 1 unique character using the esum .

Comment: @Snippet In `(a string of length is 8) == (a string of length is 8)`, although it seems that there's only 1 comparison, there are actually 8.